# Error reading xls file with pd.read_excel: ValueError: Excel file format cannot be determined, you must specify an engine manually

Tags: python, pandas, xls, valueerror

I tried run a simple code reading a xls file and it returned the error in the title

when i try run this code:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import *
import os

print('Reading Sheets')
df_ccc_lll_22 = pd.read_excel(r'U:\OOO\CCCO\PPP CCC HHH.xls')
```

it returns this error:

```
Exception has occurred: ValueError
Excel file format cannot be determined, you must specify an engine manually.
  File "U:\OOO\CCCO\teste.py", line 15, in <module>
    df_ccc_lll_22 = pd.read_excel(r'U:\OOO\CCCO\PPP CCC HHH.xls')
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: Excel file format cannot be determined, you must specify an engine manually.
```

I don't know what to do, i tried openpyxl and it also returns an error saying the file is not Zip. xlrd didnt work as well

Comment: What's with all the extra carets (`^`)? I guess you doctored the error message to censor the real filename, eh? Ideally it's best to not do that; instead make a [mre] with no sensitive info. For more info see [Why should I post complete errors?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341) BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow, if no one's said it already! :) Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want more tips.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding `xls` extension, the library typically used is `xlrd`.

And you have to specify `xlrd` as the engine when using `read_excel`

```
pip install xlrd==1.2.0
```

```
df_ccc_lll_22 = pd.read_excel(r'U:\OOO\CCCO\PPP CCC HHH.xls', engine='xlrd')
```

If the file is not a genuine `.xls` file (even if it has an `.xls` extension), you may need to open it in Excel (or another spreadsheet program) and save it as an `.xlsx` file. Then you can read it using the `openpyxl` engine:

```
df_ccc_lll_22 = pd.read_excel(r'U:\OOO\CCCO\PPP CCC HHH.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
```